# ToolTwist Request handler or navpoint not found

Tags: tooltwist

I'm manually setting up a ToolTwist webapp on a server, and everything is working normally, except every time I call a request handler I get an error reply and the following error in catalina.out.

> 2012-07-05 09:35:03,680 ERROR RoutingUIM - ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR
>   2012-07-05 09:35:03,680 ERROR RoutingUIM - Unknown request handler: op=myproject.widgets.selectName.selectName

I've checked the log files to make sure the extension project is getting loaded, and that the navpoint is getting loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ToolTwist server has the ability to switch from one project to another as a configuration option. This simplifies development, where a developer may be working on multiple projects intermittently, and doesn't want to set up multiple Tomcat servers.

At the same time, the developer doesn't want the pages for one project being effected by the navpoints or request handlers from another project.

To keep the projects separated, tooltwist.conf has a parameter named 'mainProject' for each defined web application. If the developer switches web applications in the config files, then the server will automatically be restricted to the navpoints and request handlers of that new webapp. The

So, if your website is not finding request handlers but you can see them defined on the filesystem, then it is probable that your mainProject is set incorrectly in tooltwist.conf.

```
<webapp>
    <name>webdesign</name>
    <mainProject>ttdemo</mainProject>
    ...
<webapp>
```

Note that the navpoints and requests handlers of projects included by the main project (defined in it's project.xml) are also available.